# Java WatchService ..listening to directories on Network

Tags: java, service, directory, watchservice

I am trying to `listen to directories` over the network [All on Windows] for `Create`/ `Modify`/ `Delete` events. It seems `WatchService` doesnt work for directories over network.

Any 3rd party library or any alternatives would be highly appreciated.

Mapping network drives is not an option for me since I have **more than 50 directories** to listen to .

Comment: Can you not map a share where you monitor the sub-directories or are you monitoring 50 shares?

Comment: I have more than 50 directories and the list of directories can change since the list if configurable

Comment: Even tried mapping to a directory on experimental basis, but was unable to listen to the events. The local Dev box runs on Windows Enterprise

Comment: Java uses underlying OS calls to implement this functionality.  As a result Java is at the mercy of the OS when it does this.

Comment: Thanks Peter; any 3rd party library you think which may serve the purpose?

Comment: You could try http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfilewatcher/